# How to make a controller variable to be a link inside a table cell?

Tags: thymeleaf

There is a variable from the controller :

```
model.addAttribute("nomGrilleTarif", "Tarif simple");
```

I know to show a controller variable inside a table cell : `<td th:text="${nomGrilleTarif}"></td>`

But how to make it a link ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
  <a href="https://your.url.here" th:text="${nomGrilleTarif}" />
</td>
```

Comment: but how to make it a thymeleaf url pointing to a controller ?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking... use `th:href` instead of `href`?